# Why is the response i recieve at the front-end undefined

Tags: json, django, rest, undefined, response

Why am i getting an when sending the post request.When i pass in the response body a string i dont get errors and it works perfectly fine but when i pass an complex element like this in json-like form it doesnt work.

```
def main(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response({
            "name": "PPP",
            "lastName": "UUU"
        })
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = request.body
            data = json.loads(data)
            P.pom1=data['poz1']
            P.pom2=data['poz2']
            CompMove()
            return Response({"poz1":P.pom1,
                             "poz2":P.pom2})
        except:
            return Response({"GRESKA"})
        

 - List item
```

Comment: `return Response({"GRESKA"})` is a set, that makes not much sense.

Answer (score 0):

`return Response({"GRESKA"})` will return a set with a string, not a dictionary.

You can return data for example with:

```
return Response({'GRESKA': 'foo'})
```

The assignment to `P.pom1` is also "stange": there is no `P` defined in the code fragment you share here, but even if there is, it looks like you are then working with a global object, which is often not a good idea.

Comment: The problem happened to lie in the CompMove function.And ye there was some syntax errors too,thank you for contribution sir.